# addsubview into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to add a loading view in a UItableView controlled by an UITableViewController class

I've tried:

```
-(void) loadingThread {
[self.txtComentario resignFirstResponder];
[self.myLoadingView setHidden:NO];
UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window;
[window addSubview:self.myLoadingView];
[self.myLoadingView setHidden:NO];
}
```

and have tried too:

```
-(void) loadingThread {
    [self.txtComentario resignFirstResponder];
    [self.myLoadingView setHidden:NO];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.myLoadingView];
    [self.myLoadingView setHidden:NO];
       }
```

Comment: Just try adding "[self.view addSubview: yourLoadingView]". Here "seld.view" is UITableView as you mentioned you are using "UITableViewController". Also try setting "yourLoadingView.frame = self.view.frame".

Comment: Its impossible to self.view addSubview in UItableViewcontroller

Comment: Why it is impossible? "self.view" is UITableView and it is subclass of UIView.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you might try that don't require subviews on `UITableViewController`'s `view`.

1. Fix the problem - a tableview that makes a user wait is a problem. Use dummy information to display something instantly, then update the cell content as information is received. You see this a lot with images where a placeholder is displayed then when the image is received the image replaces the placeholder. There is nothing to stop you doing that with other kinds of information such as text. Use "User name" in a light grey for example, like a text field does with its placeholder text.
2. Use a dummy cell to hold your subview. Until your data is ready to display, make your tableview hold just one cell, with the activity indicator added to that cell's `contentView`. When data arrives remove the dummy cell and display normal content.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to show a busy indicator while loading something, I'd strongly suggest that you use one of the existing libraries such as [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD).

Comment: But is a customized view

Comment: Yes, MBProgressHUD supports custom views! Check out demo app, here is the link to relevant source code line: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/blob/master/Demo/Classes/HudDemoViewController.m#L144